# Pandas iterrows give result of only last row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

The following code reads a csv file and iterate over rows of 'sub' column:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Subs_test.csv", usecols= ['sub'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(row['sub']).subscribers
subreddit
```

**my problem:**

It is giving me the result of the last row only.
Can you please help me with what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Because you keep redefining `subreddit` in the loop. Only its last incarnation survives once you leave the loop

Comment: Perhaps that you are overwritting `subreddit ` at each iteration?

Comment: ^^ Last Incarnation :D

Comment: No need to iterate explicitly anyway. `df['sub']= df['sub'].apply(lambda x: reddit.subreddit(x).subscribers)` and remove the `for` loop. Can't test on my phone but I think that should work

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, that probably returns a list so maybe you are better pulling it out of the DF. I don't know the API. If it returns an integer count of subscribers, then it's fine to keep in the DF, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you set subreddit in the loop. It will always equals for last row

for example

```
In [1]: for i in range(10):
   ...:     a = i
   ...: a
Out[1]: 9
```

If you want to put values to list you can use loops like this

```
df = pd.read_csv("Subs_test.csv", usecols= ['sub'])
subreddit = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    subreddit.append(reddit.subreddit(row['sub']).subscribers)
subreddit
```

Or list comprehension

```
subreddit = [reddit.subreddit(row['sub']).subscribers for index, row in df.iterrows()]
print(subreddit)
```

Comment: Damn, guess you were faster than me ;)

Comment: @Flob no problem dude, I already voted for your answer :) It corrected and useful too

Answer (score 2):

As was already pointed out in the comments, you redefine `subreddit`during every iteration, which is why at the end of your code, its value is the last row only. I'm guessing what you want is a list of all rows, or something similar. Solve this using a list comprehension:

```
subreddit = [reddit.subreddit(row['sub']).subscribers for index, row in df.iterrows()]
```

which will return a list of all rows.